# Getting "Cannot set property 'src' of null" but the element exists

Tags: javascript, null, document, getelementbyid

I have this function which is trying to change the src property of an img. Here's the Javascript:

```
function transition(){
    document.getElementById("firstfirst").src = marray[currArrayValue];
    currArrayValue++;
    if(currArrayValue == array.length-1){
        currArrayValue = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(transition(), 1000);
}
```

My google chrome console is saying document.getElementById("firstfirst") doesn't exist, but it definitely does. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="banners-container">
    <div id="banners">
        <img src="images/banners/top-banner-one.png" id="firstfirst" alt="Subscribe now to get access to thousands of vintage movies!" border="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

What gives?

Comment: When are you calling the function?

Comment: That `setTimeout()` call needs to be `setTimeout(transition, 1000);`

Comment: @SLaks I think it's clear that it's being called before the element is on the page, because otherwise the recursion would have blown up.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a JsFiddle?

Comment: Are you calling the function after image is being displayed? or that javascript call is made before body has completely loaded?

Comment: Thank you Pointy, what you said fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed as soon as it has been parsed.

If your JS is included in the `<head>` of your webpage, it will be executed before the document body has been parsed and the DOM has been built.

As such, you need to engineer your code so that it is not executed until the DOM has been loaded. You might want to look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference%2FDOMContentLoaded) on the DomContentLoaded event. Alternatively, you can use one of the many JavaScript libraries out there which wrap this up for you.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by changing setTimeout(transition()... to setTimeout(transition, as Pointy suggested.

Answer (score -1):

if chrome says the element is null it is null. Perhaps you are calling function before the element loaded in DOM. like calling the function in head tag prior the element tag.

so try something like this.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>
      function F () { /*reach element*/ }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   //The element
</body>
<script>
   F ();
</script>
</html>
```